# Solve ODE $x'=x^2$ using Power Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need to solve $x'=x^2$, $x(0)=1$ using the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^{n}$ and show that it has a solution on $(-1,1)$ that can be extended to $(-\infty,1)$.

I have rewritten the ODE as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{na_n t^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^{2n}=0$ and then as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)a_n t^{n}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^{2n}=0$.

Here I don't know how to continue, I would be very grateful for a step by step solution, because I still need to solve more problems like this one.

Comment: Solve the equations for the coefficients. For this recall the identity theorem. If a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n t^n =0$ for $t$ in some nonempty open interval, then $b_n=0$ for all $n$. Thus, you can recursively solve for the coefficients. Start with the coefficent in front of $t^0$. There we get $(0+1)a_0 - a_0=0$, i.e. no condition at all. Next the term in front of $t$. There we get $(1+1)a_1-0=0$ (as the second power series only contains even powers). Hence, $a_1=0$. For the coefficient in front of $t^2$, we get $(2+1)a_2-a_1=0$, thus, $a_2=0$ (as $a_1=0$). Then go on.

Comment: Perhaps $x(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$.  Find the first few terms, then guess the form.

Comment: Thank you! I think I know how to solve it now

Answer (score 1):

- If you suppose that there exists a solution in power series of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n t^n$, then $y'=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^n$
- By Cauchy product $y^2=(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nt^n)\cdot (\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nt^{n})=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_nt^{n}$ with $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}a_{n-k}$.
- Thus, $x'=x^2$ can be written as $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n t^n$ and so $c_n=(n+1)a_{n+1}$.
- Equality  coefficients: If $n=0$, then $c_0=a_0^2$ but then $a_1=a_0^2$. If $n=1$, then $c_1=a_0a_1+a_1a_0=2a_0a_1$ but then $2a_0a_1=2a_2$. If $n=2$, then $c_2=a_0a_2+a_1a_1+a_2a_0=2a_0a_2+a_1^2$ but then $3a_3=2a_0a_1+a_1^2$.

Try to guess a formula for $a_n$ inductively and then use the initial condition for to find the particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in replacing $x^2$ with its series form. Looks like all you did was swap out $t^n$ for $t^{2n}$. There's [much more to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) that makes solving the ODE with this method more complicated.

Assuming a series solution

$$x(t) = \sum_{n\ge0} a_n t^n$$

its square, using the multinomial theorem, would be

$$x(t)^2 = \left(\sum_{n\ge0} a_n t^n\right)^2 = \sum_{n\ge0} {a_n}^2 t^{2n} + 2 \sum_{1\le m<n<\infty} a_m a_n t^{m+n}$$

Or, as a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), we have

$$x(t)^2 = \sum_{m\ge0} a_m t^m \cdot \sum_{n\ge0} a_n t^n = \sum_{m\ge0} \sum_{0\le n\le m} a_n a_{m-n} t^m$$

Neither of these look like they play nice.

**Hint**: Instead of trying to attack right away with series, make a [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) to get a linear ODE, which is much more amenable to the series method.